# Why can't I mount an image I just created on loopback?

Tags: mount, files, disk-image

I'm having trouble in general getting a disk (filesystem) image to mount, so I created a generic disk image and found it wouldn't mount either!

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=image.dd bs=1k count=2048
mkfs -i 4096 -F -v -m0 image.dd
```

So far so good.  I can run `fsck` on the image and everything is fine:

```
$ fsck.ext2 -f image.dd
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
image.dd: 11/512 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 90/2048 blocks
```

But when I try to mount it, it fails:

```
$ mkdir mnt;sudo mount -orw,loop image.dd mnt
mount: /dev/loop0: can't read superblock
```

Bizarrely, when I look at `dmesg` I see I/O errors!

```
[19994.133342] blk_update_request: 4 callbacks suppressed
[19994.133357] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3968
[19994.134218] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3968
[19994.134221] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 496, async page read
[19994.134278] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 3968
[19994.134279] Buffer I/O error on dev loop0, logical block 496, async page read
[19994.134414] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2
[19994.134418] EXT4-fs (loop0): unable to read superblock
[19994.134433] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2
[19994.134435] EXT4-fs (loop0): unable to read superblock
[19994.134446] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 2
[19994.134447] EXT4-fs (loop0): unable to read superblock
[19994.134458] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev loop0, sector 0
[19994.134460] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x0
[19994.134461] squashfs: SQUASHFS error: unable to read squashfs_super_block
```

I also tried using the `losetup` command with the same results:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 image.dd
sudo mount -orw /dev/loop0 mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your system is borked. The first two commands succeed because everything takes place in the page cache. When you actually try to mount it, the page cache is bypassed and that's when things go awry because there is something wrong with the device your files are on.

Comment: So how do I get it unborked? (incidentally, I can mount the created image from another machine)